# Adding contacts to group after receiving mail from them

Tags: contacts, groups, smartgroups, civirules

Say, for example that I want to divide my contacts into two groups, an active group (contacts from whom I've received a mail in last few months) and an inactive group (countacts from whom I haven't received an email in the last few months). Is there a way to do this in CiviCRM? I was looking at CiviRules, but couldn't really find what I was looking for.

Comment: How would you find out that you received a mail?

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP I don't know actually, I'm fairly new to this stuff and thought that there might be a way to do it

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail? Because you do not receive mail in CiviCRM, right? You receive mail in an email client like Outlook or Thunderbird. And do you then create an inbound e-mail activity in CiviCRM to record that email? Or are your thoughts based on receiving email directly into CiviCRM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [inbound email processing](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/) to activities and then a smart group based on that activity in the last 3 months.